# Installing packages from terminal

Tags: apt, dpkg, gdebi

So, I tried installing a lot of packages that are in one of my folders. In the terminal I chose directory and did: "sudo apt-get install *.deb"
I've gotten a lot of errors that say "couldn't find any package by regex" or something like this. I'm doing this on computer with no internet access. What does it mean and what wrong did I did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the terminal I chose directory and did: "sudo **apt-get** intall *.deb"

Here there are two problems:

1. intall is misspelled, it should be `install`
2. `apt-get` will install local packages if a path is provided in the way of ./package.deb or /path/to/package.deb

This should achieve the desired result

```
sudo apt-get install ./*.deb
```

This will install the packages and any dependency needed if it can find them.

Answer (score 1):

To install a.deb file you need to do the following commands on terminal,

```
cd /path/to/the/directory/contains/filename.deb
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

To install all the .deb files from a directory,you can try

```
  cd /path/to/the/directory/contains/.deb files
  sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Comment: [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Using_GDebi_to_install_packages) you have more info about installing everything in Ubuntu - bookmark at .deb packages

Comment: So it means that I must install all packages one by one? Or I can not add the "filename.deb" and it will install all of them? I read somewhere that I can do something like *.deb to install all packages that are in that directory.

Comment: I have no idea, you must read a little help of this command. I'm installing *.deb by SoftwareCenter, just double click on it